# Excel 2010 find and replace hyperlinks

Tags: excel, hyperlink, replace, excel-2010

I have the following code which doesn't seem to work when replacing hyperlinks:

```
Sub ReplacePartHyperlinkAddress()
Dim hLink As Hyperlink
Dim wSheet As Worksheet

For Each wSheet In Worksheets
    For Each hLink In wSheet.Hyperlinks
        hLink.Address = Replace(hLink.Address, "File:///C:\Users/username/AppData/roaming", "O:\Brisbane\Brisbane_Groups\Offices")
    Next hLink
Next wSheet
End Sub
```

Can somebody please help me with this, also I may be trying to execute it the incorrect way in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old link is starting with `File:///`, you should also let your new link to a (network)drive location start with that:

```
hLink.Address = Replace(hLink.Address, "File:///C:\Users/username/AppData/roaming", _
        "File:///O:\Brisbane\Brisbane_Groups\Offices")
```

Also I think your initial link looks strange, as when I create a link all slashes in the path are backward "\": `"File:///C:\Users\username\AppData\roaming"`

Comment: Sorry to reply so late but that issue was fixed, I don't even know how to be honest. It just worked on another computer, maybe it was exactly what you are saying, I might have the slashes the wrong way around.

Comment: as you can see in your Question post it is both the missing of File:/// and not the right slashes everywhere. Good it works for you.